# ORACLE SQL - Query based on foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

Heres an example of the tables i need to make a query.

The Offices Table

```
       ---OFFICES----

OFFICE_ID - DEPARTMENT - EMPLOYEE_ID - MANAGER_ID

    1     - ACCOUNTING -    1      -      1 
    2     - ACCOUNTING -    2      -      2
    3     -     IT     -    3      -      3
```

The Employees table

```
     ---EMPLOYEES---

 EMPLOYEE_ID -  NAME - SURNAME

     1        - JOHN  - DOE
     2        - JOHN2 - DOE2
     3        - JOHN3 - DOE3
```

The Managers Table

```
     ---MANAGERS---

MANAGER_ID - NAME   - SURNAME

    1     -  JOHN   - JONES
    2     -  GEORGE - GEORG
    3     -  ALEX   - JON
```

I want based on the OFFICES table to make a query and group the employees and managers based on which department they are but i am not sure how. For example :

```
           ---QUERY RESULTS---

ACCOUNTING    -     IT

JOHN DOE         JOHN3 DOE
JOHN2 DOE        ALEX JON
JOHN JONES
GEORGE GEOGE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT CASE accountingRowsFinder.name
           WHEN IS NULL THEN
               ''
           ELSE
               accountingRowsFinder.name
       END || ' ' || CASE accountingRowsFinder.surname
                         WHEN IS NULL THEN
                             ''
                         ELSE
                             accountingRowsFinder.surname
                     END AS Accounting,
       CASE ITRowsFinder.name
           WHEN IS NULL THEN
               ''
           ELSE
               ITRowsFinder.name
       END || ' ' || CASE ITRowsFinder.surname
                         WHEN IS NULL THEN
                             ''
                         ELSE
                             ITRowsFinder.surname
                     END AS IT
FROM ( SELECT rownum AS recordNumber,
              name AS name,
              surname AS surname,
              COUNT( * ) AS accountingCount
       FROM ( SELECT name,
                     surname
              FROM Employees
              JOIN Offices ON Employees.employee_id = Offices.employee_id
                          AND department = 'Accounting'
              UNION
              SELECT name,
                     surname
              FROM Managers
              JOIN Offices ON Managers.manager_id = Offices.manager_id
                          AND department = 'Accounting'
            ) accountingNamesFinder
     ) accountingRowsFinder
FULL JOIN ( SELECT rownum AS recordNumber,
                   name AS name,
                   surname AS surname,
                   COUNT( * ) AS ITCount
            FROM ( SELECT name,
                          surname
                   FROM Employees
                   JOIN Offices ON Employees.employee_id = Offices.employee_id
                               AND department = 'IT'
                   UNION
                   SELECT name,
                          surname
                   FROM Managers
                   JOIN Offices ON Managers.manager_id = Offices.manager_id
                               AND department = 'IT'
                 ) accountingNamesFinder
          ) ITRowsFinder ON accountingRowsFinder.recordNumber = ITRowsFinder.recordNumber
```

This statement selects the `name` and `surname` values for every `Employee` in `Accounting` and vertically joins them to the corresponding list of `Managers` using `UNION`.  The records from this subquery are then assigned record numbers (also known as row numbers) and a count of all records from the subquery and then returned to the main body of the statement.

The same process is then pursued to form a similar list for the `department` `IT`.

A `FULL JOIN` (also known as a `FULL OUTER JOIN`) is then performed on the two datasets gained from our subqueries `accountingRowsFinder` and `ITRowsFinder` based on their values for `recordNumber`.  The longer list will have NULL values attached for the fields from the shorter list for those rows that do not have a corresponding entry.

The name fields from the joined dataset for each `department` are then concatenated.  A `CASE` statement is used to replace the `NULL` value with an empty string for display and concatenation purposes

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Further Reading*

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm (on `CASE`)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm (on the concatenation operator `||`)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm (on joins)

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp (on joins)

Comment: Code corrected and explanation added.  I will update my answer once I am able to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. I'm using this version 
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

[image]

```
select regexp_substr(ACCOUNTING, '[^;]+', 1, level) ACCOUNTING,regexp_substr(IT, '[^;]+', 1, level) IT
    from (
with tmp as (
SELECT  (DECODE(department, 'ACCOUNTING', empname)) ACCOUNTING
        ,(DECODE(department, 'IT', empname)) IT
  FROM (
select distinct LISTAGG(empname, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY department) over (partition by department)  empname,department from (
    select emp.name ||' '||emp.surname as empname
  ,ofc.department
  from EMPLOYEES emp
  ,Offices ofc
  where emp.EMPLOYEE_ID=ofc.EMPLOYEE_ID
  UNION
  select mgr.name||' '||mgr.surname as empname
  ,ofc.department
  from MANAGERS mgr
  ,Offices ofc
  where mgr.MANAGER_ID=ofc.MANAGER_ID 
  )
  ) 
  )
  select t1.accounting , t2.it
  from tmp t1, tmp t2
  where t1.accounting is not null
  and t2.it is not null
  )
connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(accounting, '[^;]+')) + 1;
```